# Unable to run docker-compose from ssh's shell

Tags: ssh, bash, shell

I'm working on setting up a script in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file so that I'm able to deploy a newly built Docker image to my server.

Here is how it looks so far:

```
- ssh deploy@my.private.vps '/bin/sh -c "cd /home/project/some/directory &&
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin && \
docker-compose stop web && \
docker-compose rm -f web && \
docker-compose up -d web && \
docker-compose exec web php artisan storage:link && \ 
exit"'
```

However, I keep getting "docker-compose: command not found" when running the command. Of course, docker-compose is install and available for the user 'deploy' when I log in with the user.

I found during my researches that it was because SSH doesn't load `usr/local/bin` by default. I tried to solve this issue by enabling the user's profile in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, and to export the PATH when running the script.

I'm running out of ideas on what I should try next.

What should I do?

Any idea welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
which docker-compose
```

or

```
whereis docker-compose
```

to find out what is its absolute path.

Make sure this path is added to your PATH env.

You can also just change your `docker-compose` into fullpath commands:

`/usr/local/bin/docker-compose stop web (...)`

Comment: That's a good idea, I ended up running commands such as `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec <some command>`